# jQuery.inArray not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through a list of numbers and check if that number is part of another list of numbers using jQuery.each and jQuery.inArray. jQuery.inArray does not seem to be behaving as expected.

Here is my code:

```
var some_numbers = [1, 2];
var more_numbers = [0, 1, 2];

$.each(more_numbers, function(index, value) {
  if($.inArray(value, some_numbers)) {
    console.log(value);
  }
});

console.log('Some Numbers:');
console.log(some_numbers);
```

Here is the resulting console output:

```
0
2
Some Numbers:
[1, 2]
```

Will someone please help? This is maddening.

**Edit:** Problem solved! Changed my condition to this:

```
if($.inArray(value, some_numbers) !== -1)
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I can't accept the answer for another 7 minutes, according to the dialog that appeared when I attempted to do so.

Comment: Yes, but you should accept answers to your other questions.  **EDIT** Looking through them, maybe you shouldn't; they don't have great answers.

Comment: Yeah, I just went back through and accepted what I felt qualified as a decent answer or at least what was closest to the solution that I ended up going with. Thanks again for your quick response to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns an index, not a boolean.

To check whether the element was found, you need to check whether it's `>= 0`.

Comment: Beautiful. Added to the condition "!== -1" and this solved my problem. Thank you!