# jQuery.inArray() not working as expected

Tags: jquery

What am I doing wrong here?  The idea is that I can separate the arrow key presses from anything else, but the every key press is firing the alert 'you pressed an arrow key'.  Any help would be great!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UpHV5/) here or:

```
<input id='foo'>

<script>

$('#foo').keyup(function (e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if ($.inArray(key, [37, 38, 39, 40])) {
        alert('you pressed an arrow key');
    } else {
        alert("you didn't press an arrow key");
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: `.inArray()` returns an index, not a bool. Make sure to read the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) prior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery.inArray not behaving as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304536/jquery-inarray-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: this is a duplicate, sorry

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to check if it returns an index > -1.  The index is -1 if there is no occurrence of the key in the array:

```
if ($.inArray(key, [37, 38, 39, 40]) >  -1)
```

Comment: But I want to check if the key IS in the array.  Is that possible, or do I just reverse the logic of the function?

Comment: if the index returned by that function is > -1 than that means the key IS in the array. In other words, the above will return true if it is in the array.

Comment: Thanks, My mistake is that I think it returns a boolean value

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery inArray function returns the index of the value.  For the left arrow key (37) it is returning 0 and it is being interpreted as false.  You should change your code to be >=0

```
   if ($.inArray(key, [37, 38, 39, 40]) > -1)
```

[inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Answer (score 3):

The $.inArray method returns the index of the element if it is in the array, and if it is not in the array it returns -1, so you can't use it as an if condition. Change it to:

```
if($.inArray(key, [37, 38, 39, 40]) >= 0)) {

}
```